# Loading Sequence of Storyboard

Tags: ios, view, window, storyboard, subview

I'm quite new to iOs Programming..

At the moment I'm wondering about following issue.
in AppDelegate.m within the function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(...) i tried to walk down the visual tree like 
(Note : The mainstoryboard has a TabBarController and on the initial View there is one button.

```
UIView *sv;
sv=[window subviews];
for(sv in mwSubViews){
NSLog(@"Subview's %d Description : %@ \n",i++,[sv description]);  
NSLog(@"Views Bounds: %@  :\n",sv.bounds);
NSLog(@"Views Frame: %@  :\n",sv.frame);
```

}

I'm using a single storyboard with some stuff on it.. When I do this within a ViewController controlling an Element from the storyboard, its Output is

ViewsAnimationTouchDrawing[59046:f803] Subview's 0 Description : > 
2012-04-16 20:32:48.362 ViewsAnimationTouchDrawing[59046:f803] Views Bounds: (null)  :
2012-04-16 20:32:48.363 ViewsAnimationTouchDrawing[59046:f803] Views Frame: (null)  :

May s.o. be so nice to explain me, why?
(i thought the window is already initialized and has a UIView on it..)

**Update

I'm currently reading a book about Window View Hierarchy.
The author says that typically there is one Instance of UIWindow class.
The delegate from UIApplication holds a reference to it. I played a bit with .xib Files within my application. If i manually load a Window from a xib file, assign it within the delegate to the window reference i can get the reference to the window with

```
UIWindow *mw = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

I can walk down the visual tree with the Function

```
-(void) runDownSubViewsWithCavemanDebug : (UIView*) view{
  NSArray *mwSubViews = [view subviews];
  static int i=0;
  if([mwSubViews count]==0) return;
  UIView *sv;
  for(sv in mwSubViews){
    NSLog(@"Subview's %d Description : %@ \n",i++,[sv description]);  
   NSLog(@"Views Bounds: %@  :\n",sv.bounds);
   NSLog(@"Views Frame: %@  :\n",sv.frame);
   [self runDownSubViewsWithCavemanDebug:sv];
  }
}
```

(The Call to the Function in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)

```
 MainViewController *myMainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
  NSArray *bundleResources = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:myMainVC         options:nil];
  UIWindow *mainWindow = [bundleResources objectAtIndex:0];
  self.window = mainWindow;
  self.window.rootViewController = myMainVC;
```

If i'm using a storyboard however, i can't get the window reference with .. keyWindow. 
I can get it with

```
UIWindow *realmw = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window];
```

I get the reference to the window, but the window(although i thought that it should've been initialized) has no elements in its subview.

Yeah, I think I'm just wondering about it.. Did Apple break up the View hierarchy within storyboards in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AppDelegate has a property named `window` (type UIWindow), that in turn has a property named `rootViewController` that represents the root view controller defined in the storyboard (in your case it is a UITabBarController).

The UITabBarController has a property `viewControllers` that is an NSArray of all of the viewControllers that tabbar controller manages.

If you wanted to see the details of each of the subviews on your tabbar's first view controller (i.e. on the first tab) you could do this in `didFinishLoadingWithOptions` as follows:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
NSArray *viewControllers = [tabBarController viewControllers];
UIViewController *firstVC = (UIViewController*)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]
NSArray *subviews = [firstVC.view subviews]

for (UIView *sv in subviews) {
    NSLog(@"Subview's %d Description : %@ \n", i++, [sv description]);  
    NSLog(@"Views Bounds: %@  :\n", sv.bounds);
    NSLog(@"Views Frame: %@  :\n", sv.frame);
}
```

Comment: That is correct.  I've adjusted my answer slightly to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I learned from it and i updated my post to clarify my confusion